# Can't get User getter in AuthenticationSuccessEvent

Tags: symfony, refresh-token, lexikjwtauthbundle

I tried to save User gsm data after Authentication Success Event :

```
 /**
     * @param AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccessResponse(AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $user = $event->getUser();
        dd($user);
        $gsm = isset(\json_decode($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getContent())->gsm) ? \json_decode($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getContent())->gsm : null;

        if ($user->getGsm()) { // <------   get user GSM 
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }


        $event->setData($data);
    }
```

When i tried to generate token it works fine :

[image: generate token]

but when i tried to refresh the token 
I got symfony error :

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getGsm" of class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User".
```

[image: refresh token]

The result of dd($user) is :

[image: dump user]

Comment: $event->getUser() probably doesn't return the class you want. 
If you want to use a new class as User you should implements UserInterface on it.
Actually, Symfony try to call getGsm() on Core\User\User

Comment: Did you create your own authentication or do you use FOSUserBundle ?

Comment: I edited my post for more details . actually when i use user credentials to generate token it works fine and the gsm is stored to database . But when i tried to refresh the token after expiration i got the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a getGsm method on a Symfony User class when you are actually trying to save the GSM data.

Ensure you are working on the correct user and you will need to use setGsm instead.

Comment: i edited my post for more details . getGsm works when i tired to generate token but doesn't work when tried to refresh token after expiration

Comment: What is the output of dd($user) when this happens?

Comment: i updated my post : i putted a screen shot of dump user

Comment: Provide the code with the getGsm method, the Symfony class DOES NOT have this method, you can check this here:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/User.php

Comment: yes i can't use the user inside core user class i have to get user by calling security or try to set the gsm out of this class